# Usaco. Friday the thirteen. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, logic, task, days

I've made a program for the USACO task and now I just can't figure out why I'm getting the bad answer, I've been thinking why for a long time and still didn't figure it out. What could be wrong?

The task is to count the number of times the 13th falls on Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, ..., Friday. The year from when to test is 1900 and the last year is given in the txt file.

Instead of this answer: 36 33 34 33 35 35 34

I'm getting:            34 33 33 33 36 36 35

Thank you very very very much for you help, I really apreciate your time and your help :)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int weekDayCount(int days, int weekDays[], int & currentWeekDay)
{

for(int day = 1; day <= days; day++)
{      
    if(day == 13)
    {
        weekDays[currentWeekDay]++;
    }

    currentWeekDay++;

    if(currentWeekDay == 7) currentWeekDay = 0;
}
}

int main()
{
int currentWeekDay = 0;
int years;

ifstream in("friday.in");

in >> years;

in.close();

int weekDays[7] = {0};

for(int y = 1900; y <= (1900 + years) - 1; y++) // Years
{
    cout << y << endl;

    for(int m = 1; m <= 12; m++) // Months
    {
        if(m == 11 || m == 2 || m == 10 || m == 8) // 30 days
        {
            weekDayCount(30, weekDays, currentWeekDay);
        }
        else if(m == 5) // February
        {
            if(y % 100 != 0 && y % 4 == 0) // If a leap year - 29 days
            {
                weekDayCount(29, weekDays, currentWeekDay);
            }
            else if(y % 100 == 0 && y % 400 == 0) // If a century leap year
            {
                cout << "Leap century: " << y << endl;
                weekDayCount(29, weekDays, currentWeekDay);
            }
            else // 28 days
            {
                weekDayCount(28, weekDays, currentWeekDay);
            }
        }
        else // Else 31 days
        {
            weekDayCount(31, weekDays, currentWeekDay);
        }
    }
}

cout << "Result" << endl;

 cout << weekDays[5] << " " << weekDays[6] << " " << weekDays[0] << " " << weekDays[1] << " " << weekDays[2] << " " << weekDays[3] << " " << weekDays[4] << endl;
}
```

Comment: How is February the 5th month?

Comment: Also, how can `m==2` have 30 days?

Comment: I recommend you learn to use a debugger.  It will help you in these situations.

Comment: Are you saying that the months having 30 days are November, February, October, and August?

Comment: You really should have a look in a calendar some time. Seriously. Out of 12 months, you got 7 of them wrong.

Comment: Maybe he's from another planet, you know?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews If you think those are the days of each month, a debugger is of no help at all.

Comment: Thank you for those who try to help me. But I already answered before to the first answer.

Those who hate better to stay silent than making fun of just a silly mistake. Don't know what you are trying to do with your hate comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your month comparisons are not correct.

February is the 2nd month, not the 5th.
As the second month, it doesn't have 30 days (at least since I've been alive).

You may want to swap those constants.

Comment: OH, I got it! Such a silly mistake, I just looked up the calendar wrong. Thank you very much!